ParserError when reading csv file from github
I'm getting a ParserError when I try to read a csv file directly from github:
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://github.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/tree/main/data/jj.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 41, saw 29

but if I download the file and read it from disk, it works without issues:
df = pd.read_csv('/home/data/jj.csv')


Your page is not linking to the raw CSV file but to a HTML page
You should use the raw URL:
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/refs/heads/main/data/jj.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df.head())

Output:
         date  data
0  1960-01-01  0.71
1  1960-04-01  0.63
2  1960-07-02  0.85
3  1960-10-01  0.44
4  1961-01-01  0.61

You can find the link here:


That's not the URL to get the actual data, but the link to Github.
You should use the RAW variant:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/refs/heads/main/data/jj.csv


import pandas as pd
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/refs/heads/main/data/jj.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

